# Intersection of Affine Subsets of a Vector Space.

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Hey guys I am teaching myself linear algebra and have no real way of confirming that a proof is correct. So I was wondering if the proof to this question is correct. The problem that is given is

> Show that the intersection of every collection of affine subsets of a
>   vector space is either empty or an affine subset.

My Attempt:

Let $B$ be a collection of affine subsets of the vector space W. Either its intersection is empty or non-empty. Assume $\bigcap_{V \in B} 
 V\neq \emptyset$ then if $v,w\in \bigcap_{V \in B} 
 V\neq \emptyset$ this implies that
$(\lambda v + (1-\lambda)w \in V \ \ \forall V\in  B) \Rightarrow (\lambda v +(1-\lambda)w \in \bigcap_{V \in B} 
 V)$. Since $v,w$ were abritrary it holds for all elements of the intersection of B. Thus the intersection is an affine subset and hence the proof is complete.

Note that I use the fact that $\lambda v +(1-\lambda)w \in A \ \forall v, w \in A ,\ \forall \lambda\in F$ iff A is an affine subset. Where F is the field over the vector space.

Thanks!

Comment: Yep, that works. Good job!